# address of pointer to C multi-dimension array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

Question from code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *arg[]){

    if (argc>2){
      int m=atoi(arg[1]);
      int n=atoi(arg[2]);

      int a[m][n];
      int (*p)[m][n]=&a;

      printf("p : %p, *p : %p, **p : %p\n",p,*p,**p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Main Env: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) x86-64

```
gcc main.c
./a.out 2 4
```

output:

```
p : 0xbfea7ef0, *p : 0xbfea7ef0, **p : 0xbfea7ef0
```

Question is why `p == *p == **p`. I think this may be because `a` is an array, kind of constant pointer which address is something specific, and this involves some implementation detail of gcc.

Comment: No; it isn't a quirk of GCC; it is expected and required behaviour.  Explaining it is harder than just stating that, though!

Comment: Try to picture a block of memory accessed through an organizational paradigm as decided by the typed-language you're using. Now, goto the beginning of that block; thrice. Yep. its still the same as it was the time before (and the time before that). If it helps at all, consider where the `a` array is in memory. Now thing of `&a`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]`. Do you expect any of those to be *different* ?

Comment: Arrays in C are weird.  That's the simplest explanation.

Comment: Yes @WhozCraig , value of &a and a is the same under gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behaviour is the same for fixed-size arrays and variably-modified arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { m = 3, n = 4 };
    int a[m][n];
    int (*p)[m][n] = &a;

    printf("p : %p, *p : %p, **p : %p\n", p, *p, **p);
    return(0);
}
```

On my machine, this produced:

```
p : 0x7fff6c542520, *p : 0x7fff6c542520, **p : 0x7fff6c542520
```

Of course, `p` is a pointer to a 2D array in both programs (and I shan't add the 'in both programs' qualifier again, even though it applies).  When you print `p`, you get the address of the array that's assigned to it, which is the address of `a`.  Because `p` is a pointer to a 2D array, `*p` 'is' the 2D array, but an array reference becomes a pointer to its first element in most situations, so `*p` is a pointer to `a[0]`, which is the same memory location as `a` references.  Similarly, `**p` 'is' a 1D array, but similarly, `**p` is a pointer to `a[0][0]`, which is also the same memory location as `a` references.  So, the three values are supposed to be the same, and the compiler gets it right.

That's not easy reading, but then, neither is the C that it is trying to explain.

Here's a minor variation on the original program which illustrates the sizes of the different objects pointed at by `p`, `*p` and `**p`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { m = 3, n = 4 };

    int a[m][n];
    int (*p)[m][n]=&a;

    printf("p+0 : %p, (*p)+0 : %p, (**p) + 0 : %p\n",
           (void *)(p+0), (void *)((*p)+0), (void *)((**p)+0));
    printf("p+1 : %p, (*p)+1 : %p, (**p) + 1 : %p\n",
           (void *)(p+1), (void *)((*p)+1), (void *)((**p)+1));
    return(0);
}
```

Strictly, the `%p` conversion specification should be given a `void *`; the casts here enforce that.  The original code is, officially, a bit sloppy, though there are few machines where it would matter.

The output from this was:

```
p+0 : 0x7fff63453520, (*p)+0 : 0x7fff63453520, (**p) + 0 : 0x7fff63453520
p+1 : 0x7fff63453550, (*p)+1 : 0x7fff63453530, (**p) + 1 : 0x7fff63453524
```

Note how the sizes of the objects pointed at are different, as represented by the `+1` version:

```
sizeof(*p)   = 0x30
sizeof(**p)  = 0x10
sizeof(***p) = 0x04
```

Answer (score 6):

`p` is a pointer to an array with dimensions `[m][n]`. The value of that pointer is the address of `a`, so printing `p` gets you the address of `a`.

`*p` is an array with dimensions `[m][n]`. The "value" of this as a pointer is a pointer to the first element of the array, which is `a[0]`. This is the same address as `a`.

`**p` is an array with dimensions `[n]`. The value of this pointer is a pointer to the first element of the array, which is `a[0][0]`. This is the same address as `a` again.